# How to represent complex POST data in python for requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a web form.  The payload when I actually run the query in Chrome looks like this on the inspect window...

```
    data: [{"property":"TimeQuick","value":"Active"},{"property":"TimeQuickDurationOptions","value":3},{"property":"TimeQuickStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},{"property":"TimeQuickEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},{"property":"ProviderCode","value":["FPL"]},{"property":"SellerCode","value":[""]},{"property":"Ref","value":""},{"property":"POR","value":["SOCO"]},{"property":"POD","value":["FPC"]},{"property":"Path","value":""},{"property":"ServiceIncrement","value":["DAILY"]},{"property":"TSClass","value":[""]},{"property":"TSType","value":[""]},{"property":"TSWindow","value":""},{"property":"TSPeriod","value":""},{"property":"TSSubClass","value":""},{"property":"Time","value":"Active"},{"property":"TimeDurationOptions","value":3},{"property":"TimeStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},{"property":"TimeEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},{"property":"ShowActiveData","value":true},{"property":"DaylightSavings","value":false}]
    sort: [{"property":"TOL","direction":"DESC","root":"data"}]
    pagingEnabled: 1
    page: 1
    limit: 50
```

I tried to represent that as a python variable like this

```
    datareq = [
             ('data', 
              {'property':'TimeQuick', 'value':'Active'},
              {"property":"TimeQuickDurationOptions","value":'3'},
              {"property":"TimeQuickStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
              {"property":"TimeQuickEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
              {"property":"ProviderCode","value":["FPL"]},
              {"property":"SellerCode","value":[""]},
              {"property":"Ref","value":""},
              {"property":"POR","value":["SOCO"]},
              {"property":"POD","value":["FPC"]},
              {"property":"Path","value":""},
              {"property":"ServiceIncrement","value":["DAILY"]},
              {"property":"TSClass","value":[""]},
              {"property":"TSType","value":[""]},
              {"property":"TSWindow","value":""},
              {"property":"TSPeriod","value":""},
              {"property":"TSSubClass","value":""},
              {"property":"Time","value":"Active"},
              {"property":"TimeDurationOptions","value":3},
              {"property":"TimeStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
              {"property":"TimeEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
              {"property":"ShowActiveData","value":'true'},
              {"property":"DaylightSavings","value":'false'}
              ),
             ('sort',
              {"property":"TOL","direction":"DESC","root":"data"}
              ),
             ('pagingEnabled', 1),
             ('limit', 50)

             ]
```

When I ran `s.post(myurl, data=datareq, cert=mycerts)` I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-78-37ee269ebbce>", line 1, in <module>
        logblah=s.post(myurl, data= datareq, cert=mycerts)

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
        prep = self.prepare_request(req)

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
        hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
        self.prepare_body(data, files, json)

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\models.py", line 499, in prepare_body
        body = self._encode_params(data)

      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\python\requests\models.py", line 97, in _encode_params
        for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):

    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I'm assuming the problem is in the way I've structured my `datareq` variable.  What would be the proper way to make that POST?

**Edit/Update:**
I've tried each of Alex and Ivan's suggestions but neither work.  They each give me a cryptic message from the server that `success=false`.  If I try them with `json=datareq` instead of `data=datareq` then I get a response from the server with 0 results even though it should have many so it seems like that is getting closer but still not all the way.

Comment: According to the requests documentation having repeating keys like you have the data should be in the format of `[('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2')]`. So a list of tuples. You have a 3rd level of a dictionary in your tuple and I think that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: @paul41 What you're saying makes sense but it's still not clear how to do it right since the data comes through with 3 levels ie. data= property=timequick

Comment: The boolean fields (`DaylightSavings` and `ShowActiveData`) should be represented as `True` and `False` rather than `'true'` and `'false'`. Depending on how the server interprets booleans, this could be cutting down your search results.

Comment: You have not included enough information here. Most importantly: what *content type* is being used when posting that data?

Answer (score 2):

Is the server expecting the POST body to be of type `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If it's json, then use the syntax `request.post(url, json=payload_dict, ....)` (note the `json` kwarg instead of `data`). If you use `data` then it assumes content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and `json` assume json. If it is indeed expecting json, which would make sense because the data is nested a few levels deep, then I'll expand upon @Işık Kaplan's answer:

```
# the dict as posted by @Işık Kaplan
payload = {
    "data": [
        {"property": "TimeQuick", "value": "Active"}, 
        {"property": "TimeQuickDurationOptions", "value": 3},
        {"property": "TimeQuickStartDate", "value": "05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
        {"property": "TimeQuickEndDate", "value": "05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
        {"property": "ProviderCode", "value": ["FPL"]},
        {"property": "SellerCode", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "Ref", "value": ""},
        {"property": "POR", "value": ["SOCO"]},
        {"property": "POD", "value": ["FPC"]},
        {"property": "Path", "value": ""},
        {"property": "ServiceIncrement", "value": ["DAILY"]},
        {"property": "TSClass", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "TSType", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "TSWindow", "value": ""},
        {"property": "TSPeriod", "value": ""},
        {"property": "TSSubClass", "value": ""},
        {"property": "Time", "value": "Active"},
        {"property": "TimeDurationOptions", "value": 3},
        {"property": "TimeStartDate", "value": "05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
        {"property": "TimeEndDate", "value": "05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
        {"property": "ShowActiveData", "value": True},
        {"property": "DaylightSavings", "value": False}],
    "sort": [
        {"property": "TOL", "direction": "DESC", "root": "data"}
    ],
    "pagingEnabled": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 50,
}

# assuming you have variables named `s`, `myurl`, and `mycerts`
# note `json=payload`, not `data=payload`
s.post(myurl, json=payload, cert=mycerts)
```

Comment: It is still possible that the endpoint expects form-encoded data but each field encoded to JSON. Much less likely but still an option, especially given that the example in the question is broken out to separate fields at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would have used :

```
datareq = {
    "data": {
        "TimeQuick": 'Active',
        "TimeQuickDurationOptions":'3',
        "TimeQuickStartDate":"05/15/2019 00:00:00",
        "TimeQuickEndDate":"05/15/2019 23:59:59",
        "ProviderCode":["FPL"],
        "SellerCode":[""],
        "Ref":"",
        "POR":["SOCO"],
        "POD":["FPC"],
        "Path":"",
        "ServiceIncrement":["DAILY"],
        "TSClass":[""],
        "TSType":[""],
        "TSWindow":"",
        "TSPeriod":"",
        "TSSubClass":"",
        "Time":"Active",
        "TimeDurationOptions":3,
        "TimeStartDate":"05/15/2019 00:00:00",
        "TimeEndDate":"05/15/2019 23:59:59",
        "ShowActiveData":'true',
        "DaylightSavings":'false'
    },
    "sort": {
        "TOL": {
            "direction":"DESC",
            "root":"data"
        }
    },
    "pagingEnabled":1,
    "limit":50
}
```

and to use a given attribute:

```
print(datareq['data']['TimeQuickStartDate'])
print(datareq['sort']['TOL']['root'])
print(datareq['limit'])
```

Comment: Thanks but while that gets through `requests` the server responds with the not so informative `"success":false`

Comment: Is this a page that you can post the url for so we can test it, or is it something internal?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not publicly testable, it's a service which you'd need a login for.

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work is because the data is changed, and doesn't fit the format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although your `datareq` data structure is valid for `python` in general, it cannot be used as a `data` parameter in `requests.post` method.

It isn't written explicitly, but if you read [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for `requests` library, you can notice that `data` parameter should be either ordinary python `dict`, or a `list` of `tuple`s, **where each tuple on the top level contains exactly 2 members** - a key and a value.

And that's exactly what your `traceback` outputs:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Specifically, your first `tuple` in `datareq` is invalid:

```py
datareq = [
             ('data', 
              {'property'...
```

, because `data` should be the "key", and other `property` stuff should be the "value".

---

To make it right, `datareq` should look like this:

```py
datareq = [
    ('data', 
        (  # note tuple here
            {'property':'TimeQuick', 'value':'Active'},
            {"property":"TimeQuickDurationOptions","value":'3'},
            {"property":"TimeQuickStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
            {"property":"TimeQuickEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
            {"property":"ProviderCode","value":["FPL"]},
            {"property":"SellerCode","value":[""]},
            {"property":"Ref","value":""},
            {"property":"POR","value":["SOCO"]},
            {"property":"POD","value":["FPC"]},
            {"property":"Path","value":""},
            {"property":"ServiceIncrement","value":["DAILY"]},
            {"property":"TSClass","value":[""]},
            {"property":"TSType","value":[""]},
            {"property":"TSWindow","value":""},
            {"property":"TSPeriod","value":""},
            {"property":"TSSubClass","value":""},
            {"property":"Time","value":"Active"},
            {"property":"TimeDurationOptions","value":3},
            {"property":"TimeStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
            {"property":"TimeEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
            {"property":"ShowActiveData","value":'true'},
            {"property":"DaylightSavings","value":'false'},
        ),
    ),
    ('sort',  # same goes for the "sort" key
        (
            {"property":"TOL","direction":"DESC","root":"data"},
        ),
    ),
    ('pagingEnabled', 1),
    ('limit', 50),
]
```

Comment: This will result in Python object representations being serialised for each field value, almost certainly *not* what the endpoint can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a regular JSON as an argument to `post()`:

```
import json

datareq = {
    "data": [{"property":"TimeQuick","value":"Active"},{"property":"TimeQuickDurationOptions","value":3},{"property":"TimeQuickStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},{"property":"TimeQuickEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},{"property":"ProviderCode","value":["FPL"]},{"property":"SellerCode","value":[""]},{"property":"Ref","value":""},{"property":"POR","value":["SOCO"]},{"property":"POD","value":["FPC"]},{"property":"Path","value":""},{"property":"ServiceIncrement","value":["DAILY"]},{"property":"TSClass","value":[""]},{"property":"TSType","value":[""]},{"property":"TSWindow","value":""},{"property":"TSPeriod","value":""},{"property":"TSSubClass","value":""},{"property":"Time","value":"Active"},{"property":"TimeDurationOptions","value":3},{"property":"TimeStartDate","value":"05/15/2019 00:00:00"},{"property":"TimeEndDate","value":"05/15/2019 23:59:59"},{"property":"ShowActiveData","value":true},{"property":"DaylightSavings","value":false}],
    "sort": [{"property":"TOL","direction":"DESC","root":"data"}],
    "pagingEnabled": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 50
     }
s.post(myurl, data=json.dumps(datareq), cert=mycerts)
```

Comment: Just use the `json` argument, as it’ll handle encoding and setting the correct content type header, which you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the python representation of that data,

```
data = {
    "data": [
        {"property": "TimeQuick", "value": "Active"}, 
        {"property": "TimeQuickDurationOptions", "value": 3},
        {"property": "TimeQuickStartDate", "value": "05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
        {"property": "TimeQuickEndDate", "value": "05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
        {"property": "ProviderCode", "value": ["FPL"]},
        {"property": "SellerCode", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "Ref", "value": ""},
        {"property": "POR", "value": ["SOCO"]},
        {"property": "POD", "value": ["FPC"]},
        {"property": "Path", "value": ""},
        {"property": "ServiceIncrement", "value": ["DAILY"]},
        {"property": "TSClass", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "TSType", "value": [""]},
        {"property": "TSWindow", "value": ""},
        {"property": "TSPeriod", "value": ""},
        {"property": "TSSubClass", "value": ""},
        {"property": "Time", "value": "Active"},
        {"property": "TimeDurationOptions", "value": 3},
        {"property": "TimeStartDate", "value": "05/15/2019 00:00:00"},
        {"property": "TimeEndDate", "value": "05/15/2019 23:59:59"},
        {"property": "ShowActiveData", "value": True},
        {"property": "DaylightSavings", "value": False}],
    "sort": [
        {"property": "TOL", "direction": "DESC", "root": "data"}
    ],
    "pagingEnabled": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 50,
}
```

you don't need to put any json objects to the `request.post` any valid python dictionary would do. The only thing you need to worry about is the schema of the json for the server to accept. The python dictionary is automatically turned into json when you put it to post method automatically by the library.

Comment: You need to show **how** you’d have the library encode the data structure to JSON...

Comment: They already have that part, `.post(data=datareq, **other_stuff)` or `json=datareq` depending on what exactly server expects

Comment: They don’t have that, not in the question. And the data structure you give doesn’t work when posted with `data`.

Comment: We don't know if the server expects a form or json, if we did then I'd write it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, which is why I closed the question. But that doesn't mean your answer is in any way helpful to anyone.

Comment: Showing how the data structure should look like from what's given is not helpful? Sure, why not?